# KOAjs - A conditional inside function return false then throw custom json message

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, koa

Straight to the point, how can I custom error message in json ?

In laravel simply

```
$query = //some query here

if ($query->status== false) {
 return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'your data is false']);
}

return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => $query]);
```

It will return your data is false response if query match with conditional. And will show the $query if query doesnt match with conditional.

When I try in Koa,

```
async invoiceHistory(ctx) {

const  query = await //some query here

if (query.status == false) {
 ctx.body = { status: "error", message: 'your data is false'} //and also how to custom code 500,400,404 etc.
}

ctx.body = {status: "success", message: query}

}
```

It will both return status = success response if query match with conditional. Its like koa is reading only the last ctx.body.

Any help will appreciate, thanks.

Comment: To be clear, you're using KOA to query Laravel, but the query.status isn't resolving correctly. Have you logged out `query` to see what the shape of the object is?

Answer (score 0):

You need an `else`:

```
if (query.status == false) {
 ctx.body = { status: "error", message: 'your data is false'} //and also how to custom code 500,400,404 etc.
} else {
  ctx.body = {status: "success", message: query}
}
```